# java 8 lambda method to process IOException from close() in try-with-resources

Tags: lambda, java-8

what is the proper syntax for Java 8 lambdas to wrap this

```
catch (Exception e) {
        throw JiraUtils.convertException(e);
}
```

and not repeat it in all methods that need this JiraRestClient?

```
@Override
public GTask loadTaskByKey(String key, Mappings mappings) throws ConnectorException {
    try(JiraRestClient client = JiraConnectionFactory.createClient(config.getServerInfo())) {
        final JiraTaskLoader loader = new JiraTaskLoader(client, config.getPriorities());
        return loader.loadTask(key);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw JiraUtils.convertException(e);
    }
}

@Override
public List<GTask> loadData(Mappings mappings, ProgressMonitor monitorIGNORED) throws ConnectorException {
    try(JiraRestClient client = JiraConnectionFactory.createClient(config.getServerInfo())) {
        final JiraTaskLoader loader = new JiraTaskLoader(client, config.getPriorities());
        return loader.loadTasks(config);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw JiraUtils.convertException(e);
    }
}
```

note: removing the catch() block leads to compilation error:

```
unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
  exception thrown from implicit call to close() on resource variable 'client'
```

here is the [link to JiraRestClient](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jira-rest-java-client/src/72119d3850d8b8bd464cef45ed756991924c4cc6/api/src/main/java/com/atlassian/jira/rest/client/api/JiraRestClient.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default):

Comment: Why is the requirement to have a solution with lambda?

Comment: feel free to share your lambda-less version that eliminates duplication in multiple methods with various logic and return parameters where they all need to create an instance of JiraRestClient, then close it and process possible closing exceptions. of course you can use a regular callback here, but I feel that lambda syntax would be the most concise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
@Override
public GTask loadTaskByKey(String key, Mappings mappings) throws ConnectorException {
  return withJiraRestClient(client -> {
    final JiraTaskLoader loader = new JiraTaskLoader(client, config.getPriorities());
    return loader.loadTask(key);
  });
}

@Override
public List<GTask> loadData(Mappings mappings, ProgressMonitor monitorIGNORED) throws ConnectorException {
  return withJiraRestClient(client -> {
    final JiraTaskLoader loader = new JiraTaskLoader(client, config.getPriorities());
    return loader.loadTasks(config);
  });
}

private <T> T withJiraRestClient(JiraRestClientAction<T> f) throws ConnectorException {
  try (JiraRestClient client = JiraConnectionFactory.createClient(config.getServerInfo())) {
    return f.apply(client);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    throw JiraUtils.convertException(e);
  }
}

@FunctionalInterface
interface JiraRestClientAction<T> {
  T apply(JiraRestClient client) throws IOException;
}
```